# Command Pattern use for Returning Data

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

I am working on an application and trying to follow Robert C. Martin's SOLID principles. I am using the Command Pattern and I was wondering about the implementation. In all of his examples in Clean Code and Agile Principles, Patterns and Practices in C# his command objects never return anything. His Command interface is;

```
public interface Command
{
  void Execute();
}
```

All of the examples are "AddEmployee", "DelEmployee", "EditEmployee", etc. Would I have a command that would be "GetAllEmployees" or is there some other special "Interactor" I would create for that specific purpose? One way I am thinking of handling that specific case is to have two interfaces a non generic like the one above and a generic one like this;

```
public interface Command<T>
{
  T Execute();
}
```

What I am asking is would this be an acceptable implementation of this pattern or is there another way we would access data from the application?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement CQS (command and query segregation). Commands should never return any data. For queries you have specific query objects. Just rename `Command<T>` to `Query<T>` and you're good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A command is something that changes state (updates, deletes or additions).

When getting data (and not changing it), you would use a *query*.

Also see [CQS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation) and the related [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Comment: I thinks introducing CQRS here can cause a lot of confusion.